# In SQL how to take rows of data and collate into a new row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table in SQL Server 2014 which stores all the process steps users have done on handheld scanners. The use of the scanners is to pick stock for sales orders.

The table has the following columns:

```
| ID | JOB_ID | FLOW_STEP_ID | SEQUENCE | SCANNED_DATA | AUDIT_TIME |
```

[example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG9EK.png)

The example data is ordered by JOB_ID ASC and AUDIT_TIME *ASC*

I need to take the SCANNED_DATA column and arrange into a new row, based on the FLOW_STEP_ID.

A JOB_ID covers the instance, i.e. if a user quits the scanning app, a new ID is created when the user reopens the app.

A JOB_ID sees the following pattern for the FLOW_STEP_ID:

1. Step 302: Order Number
2. Step 134: Warehouse bin being picked from
3. Step 97: Stock code
4. Step 99: Lot Number for stock code
5. Step 136: Quantity picked
6. Repeat points 2-5

A JOB_ID can have multiple FLOW_STEP_ID of step 302: Order number. There is a step which should signify the end of a job which is FLOW_STEP_ID of 343, however the user can close the app early, reopen it and therefore have a new JOB_ID and then trigger step 343.

The ID column is unique.

```
| JOB_ID | SALES_ORDER | BIN | STOCK_CODE | LOT | QTY | AUDIT_TIME |
|--------|-------------|-----|------------|-----|-----|------------|
```

[new format for data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDxsX.png)

The new data needs have the JOB_ID and SALES_ORDER for each row until step 302 is repeated or the JOB_ID changes.

I'm completely stuck on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```sql
CREATE TABLE #jobs (id int, job_id int,flow_step_id int,sequence int, scanned_data varchar(100),audit_time datetime)
INSERT INTO #jobs
VALUES  (8268576,116522,302,1,'somedata', dateadd(minute, -10,getdate()))
,   (8268577,116522,134,1,'0', dateadd(minute, -9,getdate()))
,   (8268578,116522,97,1,'1', dateadd(minute, -8,getdate()))
,   (8268579,116522,99,1,'2', dateadd(minute, -7,getdate()))
,   (8268580,116522,136,1,'3', dateadd(minute, -5,getdate()))
,   (8268581,116522,302,1,'somedata #2', dateadd(minute, -4,getdate()))
,   (8268581,116522,134,1,'1', dateadd(minute, -3,getdate()))
,   (8268578,116522,97,1,'2', dateadd(minute, -2,getdate()))
,   (8268579,116522,99,1,'3', dateadd(minute, -1,getdate()))
,   (8268580,116522,136,1,'4', dateadd(second, -50,getdate()))
,   (8268581,116522,302,1,'somedata #2', dateadd(second, -30,getdate()))
,   (8268581,116522,134,1,'2', dateadd(second, -29,getdate()))
,   (8268578,116522,97,1,'2', dateadd(second, -28,getdate()))
,   (8268579,116522,99,1,'3', dateadd(second, -27,getdate()))
,   (8268580,116522,136,1,'4', dateadd(second, -26,getdate()))
,   (8268581,116522,134,1,'3', dateadd(second, -25,getdate()))
,   (8268578,116522,97,1,'3', dateadd(second, -24,getdate()))
,   (8268579,116522,99,1,'4', dateadd(second, -23,getdate()))
,   (8268580,116522,136,1,'5', dateadd(second, -22,getdate()))

SELECT  job_id, batch, batch2
,   max(CASE WHEN flow_step_id = 134 THEN scanned_data END) AS bin
,   max(CASE WHEN flow_step_id = 97 THEN scanned_data END) AS code
,   max(CASE WHEN flow_step_id = 99 THEN scanned_data END) AS lot
,   max(CASE WHEN flow_step_id = 136 THEN scanned_data END) AS qty
,   min(audit_time) AS start
from (
    select *
    , SUM(CASE WHEN flow_step_id = 134 THEN 1 END) OVER(partition BY job_id, batch ORDER BY audit_time, id) AS batch2
    FROM    (
      SELECT    *, SUM(CASE WHEN flow_step_id = 302 THEN 1 END) OVER(partition BY job_id ORDER BY audit_time, id) AS batch
      FROM  #jobs
    ) x
    ) y
where batch2 is not null
GROUP BY job_id, batch, batch2

DROP TABLE #jobs
```

This creates a batch id which is just a counter on how many times flow_step 302 was seen. So each new 302 increments it. It's important that they actually start by scanning 302, otherwise it won't work.

Then i do a little conditional aggregation to create the bin, lot, code, qty columns. If you have some stable "sort order" which isn't audit_time, you can use that instead.

Output:

| job_id | batch | batch2 | bin | code | lot | qty | start |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 116522 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 2023-07-24 10:01:13.047 |
| 116522 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 2023-07-24 10:07:13.047 |
| 116522 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 2023-07-24 10:09:44.047 |
| 116522 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 2023-07-24 10:09:48.047 |

Comment: This is great, thank you. I've noticed when I add another pattern of flow steps 302-136, the table has batch 1 and 3, and misses 2. Also when I have multiple steps of 134-136 between steps 302, it only displays the last set of data, instead of creating a new row for each batch of steps between 302.

Comment: For #1, i don't know, it's probably because of your dates aren't correct? There needs to be a correct order of transactions timewise for this stuff to work. For #2, yeah, that's a miss in the code, i didn't see that you wanted to have multiple picking per order

Comment: edited the logic a bit and created a second batch when you pick multiple rows per order. It's not super perfect, but you should be able to do something with it